# How to update an array item in MongoDB with two "where" condition using java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, nosql

I have a collection called "XX" and in this collection I have several documents. I am matching on the field "userEmail".

This is the structure of the document:

```js
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5331e4e313163623bb649249"} ,
   "userEmail" : "user3@this.com"} 
   "reservations" : [ { 
        "idRest" : "23" , 
        "userPhone" : "88888888" , 
        "date" : "03-13-2015" , 
        "hour" : "14:30" 
   },
   { 
        "idRest" : "24" , 
        "userPhone" : "88888888" , 
        "date" : "03-13-2015" , 
        "hour" : "17:30" 
   },
   { 
        "idRest" : "22" , 
        "userPhone" : "88888888" , 
        "date" : "03-13-2015" , 
        "hour" : "16:30" 
  }]
```

}

And now I need find the document where "userEmail" = "some@some.com" and update the fields of the array where "idRest" = 24. in this case:

```js
{ 
    "idRest" : "24" , 
    "userPhone" : "88888888" , 
    "date" : "03-13-2015" , 
    "hour" : "17:30" 
},
```

Can you help me please to build the query using JAVA driver :) thanks in advance!!

---

**EDIT**: this is my code, but instead of update the fields add a new sub document

`

```
DBCollection collReservationByUser = db.getCollection(usersReservationCollection);

DBObject queryx = new BasicDBObject("userEmail", rest.getEmailUser());

BasicDBObject document1 = new BasicDBObject();

document1.put("idRest", rest.getEmailUser());
document1.put("userPhone", rest.getPhoneUser());
document1.put("date", rest.getFecha());
document1.put("hour", rest.getHora());;

DBObject update1 = new BasicDBObject();
update1.put("$push", new BasicDBObject("reservations", document1));
collReservationByUser.update(queryx, update1, true, true);`
```

Comment: did you try writing it yourself and run into any issues?  if yes, please post your code and the error here.

Comment: thanks, I add my code. instead of update the fields add a new sub document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shell, you could do this using a command like:

```js
db.XX.update(
    // Find the document where userEmail=some@some.com and find the element in the "reservations" array where idRest=24
    {
        "userEmail":"some@some.com", 
        "reservations.idRest":24
    }, 
    // Update the element matched by the find criteria with new values
    {
        $set:{
           "reservations.$.idRest":99, 
           "reservations.$.userPhone":"888888", 
           "reservations.$.date":"03-13-2015", 
           "reservations.$.hour":"17:30"
        }
    }
)
```

And the Java equivalent will look like:

```java
    ...
    DBObject selectQuery = new BasicDBObject("userEmail", rest.getEmailUser());
    selectQuery.append("reservations.idRest", rest.getId());

    BasicDBObject updateFields = new BasicDBObject();
    updateFields.put("reservations.$.idRest", rest.getEmailUser());
    updateFields.put("reservations.$.userPhone", rest.getPhoneUser());
    updateFields.put("reservations.$.date", rest.getFecha());
    updateFields.put("reservations.$.hour", rest.getHora());;

    DBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    updateQuery.put("$set", updateFields);
    collReservationByUser.update(selectQuery, updateQuery, true, true); 
    ...
```

**Note:** If the "reservations" array has multiple elements with "idRest"=24, then the above query will **only update the first matched element**.  It's not possible to update multiple elements within an array using positional operator.

Comment: Please tell me if i want to search record on similar condition approach then , How to write java code ?

Answer (score 0):

Updating is not much different, see the [`.update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) method in the documentation. But you will want the [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator instead:

```
DBObject queryx = new BasicDBObject("userEmail", "some@some.com");
queryx.put("idRest", 24);


BasicDBObject document1 = new BasicDBObject();

document1.put("idRest", rest.getEmailUser());
document1.put("userPhone", rest.getPhoneUser());
document1.put("date", rest.getFecha());
document1.put("hour", rest.getHora());

DBObject update1 = new BasicDBObject();

update1.put("$set", new BasicDBObject("reservations.$", document1));
collReservationByUser.update(queryx, update1);`
```

You also do not need all the fields so to just update "userPhone" change to this:

```
BasicDBObject document1 = new BasicDBObject();
document1.put("reservations.$.userPhone", rest.getPhoneUser());

DBObject update1 = new BasicDBObject();

update1.put("$set", document1);
collReservationByUser.update(queryx, update1);`
```

This relies on the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator in order to work on the "matching" index of the array.

Comment: @Kramnik0 Which part is a problem for you? Your problem *seemed* to be  "matching" the element you wished to update.

Comment: yes, I need update the fields, thank you for your help, but the other answer was the solution to my problem.